# left align images breaks ul block

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists, leftalign

Aligning the ***image(400x100)*** left breaks the `ul` block: some items are on the right side of the image, some items are under the image. How to make the `ul` block stay together? i.e. all items are on the right side of the image. Also the image overlaps with the `ul` block.

```html
<img src="url" align="left">

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `display: inline-block;` to your `<ul>`. This sets the `<ul>` to be displayed in the same line as the image, thus keeping it together as follows:

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="url" align="left">

<div>
<ul>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why display:inline-block works, but display:block not working? Thanks

Comment: `display: inline-block` is different from `display: block`. `inline-block` says to the browser that you want the element in the same line as the previous element. `block` just says that you want it to be displayed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is remove the `align="left"` attribute from your `img` element as all elements are left aligned by default and the align attribute is typically only reserved for the `table` element by default. The `img` and `div` elements have the `display: block;` attribute by default. There are two decent solutions for your problem.

**1. Float the two elements and don't forget to clear your floats.** You should also get in the habit of indenting properly so you can see the parent child relationship in your HTML structure.

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
      <img src="#">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    img,
    div {
        float: left;
    }

    .container {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

**2. Set both elements to be inline-block elements.**

CSS

```
    img,
    div { 
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case:

```
ul {
  clear: left;
}
```

(if you want the ul below the image)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRENMB

(But you should use a class for the ul and the rule, so that other `ul`s won't be affected)